# SDWebImage how to configure SDImageCache

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I am updating SDWebImage (4.0.0) and currently refactoring my old code. As the release notes say: "SDImageCache configuration properties moved into SDImageCacheConfiguration (which is now available via config property)". I used to configure it by accessing the configuration properties of the shared SDImageCache instance I need. Based on the release notes and Objective-C header files I tried to update my code to this:

`SDImageCache.shared().config.shouldCacheImagesInMemory = false`

Xcode is telling me that SDImageCache has no member "config" even though I am able to see the config property in SDImageCache.h. I am not sure how to configure the SDImageCache instance.

I would appreciate any help, thank you very much.

Edit: I am able to access another method from SDImageCache.h but .config is still not working

Comment: Did you import `SDImageCache.h` in your bridging header? I used the above syntax in Swift 3 with the latest SDWebImage and it worked fine. If you're still having problems, you might need to share more information about your configuration so we can figure out how to reproduce your error.

Comment: Yes I have imported it the way it's said on their github. `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`

Comment: When I did it in Carthage, I just created my `Cartfile`, did `carthage update`, added the library, did the `copy-frameworks` stuff, and then all I needed in my Swift file was `import SDWebImage` (no bridging header). When I manually add SDWebImage source to my project, I just added the `.h`/`.m` files, added the bridging header when prompted and then `#import`ed `UIImageView+WebCache.h` in my bridging header, and it worked fine. (`UIImageView+WebCache.h` imports `#import "SDWebImageManager.h"`, which imports `SDImageCache.h`).

Comment: How precisely did you add SDWebImage to your project? Via Cocoapods or Carthage, or manually?

Comment: If you used Cocoapods, make sure you got 4.0. Their example `podfile` has `~>3.8` in their documentation, and I presume you want `~>4.0` (or lose that qualifier entirely).

Comment: You should be able to use `import SDWebImage` in your Swift code to get access to the entire framework. You shouldn't need to put anything in your bridging header.

Comment: @DaveWeston - It depends upon how SDWebImage is added to the project. If added as separate target/library, then, yes, `import SDWebImage` is sufficient. If the SDWebImage source was just added to the existing target, then, `import` is not appropriate, but rather you need the bridging header stuff. But what doesn't make sense is the error that says it can't find `config` property; If SDWebImage wasn't found at all, he'd get a different error about `SDWebCache`, instead. That's why I wonder whether he's really installed the version he thinks he has.

Comment: I'm using Cocoapods and I did make sure that I am using 4.0. I also already refactored some code that had to be changed due to SDWebImage update. Tried deleting derived data but that didn't seem to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for a solution this commit worked for me:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/commit/add652e156eb5b7377d527cdbd9082d46d5d458c

Comment: I hate when these library authors don't bump their GitHub releases when they do these commits. It's frustrating that we were both allegedly looking at version 4.0.0, but yours didn't include this commit. (Sigh.)

Comment: Yes I actually accidentally saw this commit. Apparently will be out on version 4.1. Thank you for your help though!